# How LSTM compare which information is important or not?

Tags: neural-networks, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, weights

I am interested to know, if I have scaled my data between `[0,1]`, and have a vector like `[0, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1]`, is that mean the LSTM will forget `0.01`? What if I scaled my data between `[-1,1]` or if I don't scale my data?

I mean what data will throw out and what data will be kept through a LSTM network training?

Comment: Your question can not be answered with the information you provided. The output/reaction of the LSTM does not only depend on the input, but also on the model parameters that are adapted during training.

Comment: @NikolasRieble: Model parameters like what? Explain more pleaase.

Comment: https://medium.com/mlreview/understanding-lstm-and-its-diagrams-37e2f46f1714